# Is there anyway to increase the size of an input.text element?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

```
I want to increase the size of the input box so when I email it it's actually usable for users to enter info, this is the best I could come up with but it's not changing size. I think it's not even possible?

{
    
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "Container",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "Input.Text",
                    "id": "multilineInputId",
                    "placeholder": "enter comment",
                    "isMultiline": true,
                    "value": "EDITABLE TEXT",
                    "height":"auto"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.Http",
            "title": "Click me!",
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "https://contoso.com/api/...",
            "body": "<body of the POST request>",
            "headers": [
                {
                    "name": "Content-Type",
                    "value": "application/json"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This was being worked on by the Adaptive Cards team, but I can't recall the exact timeline. See the Feb community call for more info: https://youtu.be/SEsjrFIf110

It's not clear if this will adjust the textboxes as well, or just the card size itself, but in either case, make sure you adaptive card itself is at least 1.2 (it's current version 1.0)